# Close BCP window without seeing it finish

Tags: sql-server, bcp

A user executes the following bcp command locally to import data into SQL Server database.

> bcp TEST_DB.dbo.TEST_TABLE IN TEST_TABLE.dat -N -T

Generally, the command prompt window may display output messages like the following.

(The SQL Server database is using Simple Recovery Model.)

```
================================================================================

Starting copy...

1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 1000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 2000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 3000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 4000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 5000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 6000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 7000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 8000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 9000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 10000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 11000
1000 rows sent to SQL Server. Total sent: 12000

12406 rows copied.
Network packet size (bytes): 4096
Clock Time (ms.) Total     : 75     Average : (165413.3 rows per sec.)

================================================================================
```

The problem is, when user executes bcp to import millions of rows into a table, he finds that it takes a long time to see the message "XXXXX rows copied." appears. Therefore, he decides to close the command prompt window deliberately (by clicking the "X" button in upper right corner of window) before bcp completion. No Ctrl-C keystroke has been invoked.

What problem could be induced by this unexpected behavior?

Comment: Is this a homework question?

Comment: Nope, it's just something my coworker did on a test database yesterday. If the level of this question is considered as a homework question, I will withdraw my question and seek answer elsewhere.

Comment: It would be helpful if you mentioned a bit more detail; like is this a filtered select BCP command from a flatfile, is this over LAN/WAN/Local Disk. As for the 'unexpected behavior' - what exactly is expected and not expected. What is the expectation from your user/coworker on BCP of millions of rows into SQL? When you close the command window, you essentially kill the insert. If said coworker/user doesn't want to look at it, schedule the batch file as a SQL Agent job to run without an actual command window.

Comment: @HenricoBekker Thank you very much for your comment. What makes me feel strange is that my coworker claimed that even though he closed the bcp window before it completed, he could query the table and find the data he expected to import into. But I expect that bcp process should be considered killed, as you pointed out. With your answer, I think I will have to discuss with my coworker further about the exact situation for this bcp execution. Thanks again.

Comment: When he runs the BCP utility, open Task Manager and see the BCP.exe as a service running, when closed, the obvious will happen. Refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility for more information.

Answer (score 1):

After running some experiments based on the situation described by my coworker, I think it's safe to conclude that by closing BCP window before completion, the BCP process is actually terminated, and the bulk insert command is rolled back. But it may take some time to explain the reason why he can get the data he wants.

According to his description and some assessment of database settings, following is what happened yesterday :

1. There is a staging table in the database, with PK constraint and a few indexes present.
2. He opens a command prompt window, and execute BCP to import a native format data file containing some 50 millions of data rows into staging table (with command options : -N -T)
3. BCP executes smoothly, until the final "1000 rows sent to SQL Server" message appears. The message "XXXXX rows copied." just does not show up.
4. During this long, long waiting, he decides to try to feed some of the data into another table for further processing by executing a filtered SELECT command along with NOLOCK hint.
5. After he finishes reading the data rows he wants, he closes the command prompt window immediately, without seeing it finish.

Depending on existence of indexes, when using BCP to import data rows into a table, they are being inserted into target table at different stages. This can be easily confirmed by running the following SQL statement to check the number of table rows in target table along with BCP execution.

> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TEST_TABLE WITH (NOLOCK)

Since BCP is bulk inserting 50 millions rows into a table with indexes, it surely takes a long time to complete. Based on the exact point in time he issues the filtered SELECT statement, it is possible for him to retrieve the data rows he expected to see. But when he closes the command prompt window running BCP, the rollback begins, and when the rollback is done, these data rows are gone. Because the data rows he needs have already been transferred to another table, he will not be aware of what have taken place under the hood.